# How can i run a portia spider by its port?

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, portia

I am trying to run a spider with portia in its docker version but i don't want to execute the spider using a terminal command like `docker exec ... portiacrawl ...`. Is there any way I can run the spider, that is already created, by making a request at its localhost port and save it in an specific folder?

Something like:
https://localhost:9001/execute/spider_name/folder_path

Example of my own usage:

First what I do is run the container and leave it running, because i cant stop it for other reasons:

```
docker run -i -t -d --rm -v <PROJECTS_FOLDER>:/app/data/projects:rw -p 9001:9001 scrapinghub/portia
```

Next I execute the portiacrawl:

```
docker exec <CONTAINER_ID> portiacrawl <PROJECT_NAME_PATH> <SPIDER_NAME> -o /some/path/in/my/pc/<SPIDER_NAME>.json
```

Now, what i want is to replace the docker exec step with som http request to the localhost server that is running.

Thanks very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can by doing a port mapping. While starting a docker container you wont have any ports published publicly or exposed internally unless you told docker to do so.

For example:

- if you wish to expose a port internally (inside the docker network itself, you need to add `EXPOSE` in the dockerfile)
- if you wish to publish a port publicly that can be access either through localhost or the public ip you can use `-p` option along with passing the ports so in your case it will be like this:

```
docker run -p 9001:9001 imagename
```

The command above will tell docker that you would like to do port mapping from 9001 (using localhost or any other interface) to 9001 (inside the container and you can change the ports according to your actual setup).

If you wish to expose it to localhost only you can change the command to something like this:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9001:9001 imagename
```

For more information check [the following docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports)

---

According to the updated question, the other and safest way to accomplish this will be implementing an API inside `portiacrawl` that can be called through HTTP to do the needed tasks instead of using `docker exec`

Comment: Yes, but what i mean is to execute an spider when the docker container of portia is already running without using any docker command but using some kind of http request to the ui web it deploys when i run the container

Comment: If all of your containers exposed to localhost then they can contact each other using localhost without the docker commands, could you add more explanation about your setup to the question so we can help you better ?

Comment: @MarinerZZ, i guess the other option would be implement a rest api inside `portiacrawl` that do the execution for you when you call it or using docker rest api but accessing the api from within a container requires more access to the host which may not be suitable or preferred in your case.

Comment: Yes but i dont want to access to the host from the portia container but from the host it is running, so maybe creating an api rest is the only available way i can see...
Thanks for your help @Mostafa Hussein